# Ubuntu freezes on boot after a while of installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, freeze

I don't usually post here because I like to solve everything alone, but this time it's different. 
 For the past... 3 months I tried Ubuntu, Ubuntu Mate, Xubutnu and Lubunt and all of them start freezing after a while, whenever I try to log in.

I use Linux in general for more than 3 years and I never had this problem until 3 or 4 months ago. Also, to mention, I didn't tried any other Linux Distribution in the past 3 or 4 months, because I really like Ubuntu.

My computer is pretty old, it may be because of this. Here are the specifications:

```
 2x Intel(R) Core(TM)2CPU 4400 @ 2.00 Ghz.
 2 GB of RAM.
 500 gb hard disk
 Ati Radeon HD 4300/4500
```

I know the computer is pretty old and the video card is not supported, but it wasn't a problem until now. I use ubuntu mostly for work, so I don't see how the bad computer would be a problem.

So, is there any way I can avoid this? And if not, can someone recommend me a more stable Linux Distribution, that I can use without the fear or having to install another one after 1 month, except Linux Mint?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because what you're asking for is a software solution to a hardware problem, and that is hardly ever possible...  **:-(** (test your hardware and replace the broken hardware)

Comment: I understand, the only reason I asked this question is because I have a dual boot and the windows seems to work just fine.    I didn't had a problem using Windows, only with Ubuntu. Anyways, I guess I'll have to change either a certain part of my hardware or the entire computer.

Answer (score -1):

The problem sounds like a hardware issue to me. I would suggest changing your hard disk (the most likely candidate for failure) and then installing Ubuntu. If that did not work consider changing your computer. I know it is a drastic but trying to diagnose whether the motherboard, memory or something else is failing is tricky and usually not worth the effort.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that too... well, if there's not way to fix that without getting a new computer, I guess I'll have to do that... I'll use opensuse until then, or something similar.
 Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: You don't need to buy a new computer yet. Get a hard disk suitable for your machine and try loading Ubuntu on that. Remove all other harddisks. If it works put you enable your other disks and run some system checks. If all are OK then continue using them. If corrupted recover what data you can and try to rebuild any essential data.

If the problem still occurs consider replacing the entire system.